# How to share variables between two screen classes in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Before starting, I would like to say that I have tried all the methods available I could find, including this one: [passing variables between two screen classes in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080020/passing-variables-between-two-screen-classes-in-kivy)

I have a situation that looks something like this:

```
class SettingsWindow(Screen):
    important_setting = StringProperty()

    def foo():
       pass

class GameWindow(Screen):
    woo = StringProperty()
    variable = # Want to get the "important setting var here"

    def bar():
      pass
```

I should also point out that I am using the .kv file

Comment: You need to explain exactly why the solution to your linked question is insufficient here.  Your term "share" is undefined.  In its fullest sense, you *cannot* share a variable between separate classes; you surrendered that concept (common attribute) when you separated the classes.  Simply passing the desired value on demand is the typical method.

Comment: you can access variable of parent from child, but not the opposite.

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class SettingsWindow(Screen):

    important_setting = StringProperty()


class GameWindow(Screen):

    variable = StringProperty()

    def on_pre_enter():
        self.variable = self.parent.ids['settings_window'].important_setting
```

This would set GameWindow.variable to whatever SettingsWindow.important_setting is when GameWindow becomes the current window.

Of course, you would have to give SettingsWindow an id of 'settings_window' for this to work. Do this in your kv file. Presumably it would look like this (though since you didn't share your kv file, I am not too sure):

```
ScreenManager:

    SettingsWindow:
        id: settings_window  # <--- this is what you have to add to you kv file
        name: 'settings_window' 

    GameWindow:
        id: game_window
        name: 'game_window'
```

Comment: Just a little caveat, `GameWindow.variable` isn't dynamically changed each time `SettingsWindow.important_variable` is changed. It's value is only copied at the point when the screen changes.